# .htaccess rewrite with file path as parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

### Rewrite url ###
# Basic rewrite for pages in the admin area
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-z/]*)$ /private/admin/index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So the url could be someting like: `admin/overview/overview` making `overview/overview` the path. This is working fine but now I would like to add another parameter to be used as an id (for deleting / editing). So added the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-z/]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ /private/admin/index.php?path=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This is obviously not working: `admin/overview/overview/34` as everything behind `admin/` is seen as the path including `34`. But when I tried:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([a-z/]*)-([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ /private/admin/index.php?path=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Making the url `admin/overview/overview-34`, still didn't work. I also tried to place the line on different locations (before and after `RewriteRule ^admin/([a-z/]*)$ /private/admin/index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]`)

I hope someone can help me with this problem or give me an alternative way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This  should work :

```
RewriteRule ^admin/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /private/admin/index.php?path=$1/$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The edits didn't work, giving me 500 error and the pre edit was right nor wrong. I also don't really like to use 3 params ($1, $2, $3) as I would only use 2